# No support for Wildfly 9.0.0.Final in Intellij 12.1.6

Tags: intellij-idea, wildfly, intellij-12

When I add a new Application Server IntelliJ, pointing to the home path of the Wildfly 9.0.0.Final, IntelliJ shows me this warning:
"The selected directory is not a valid Jboss home"

Is this a question of Wildfly configuration someone from Wildfly team must fix or it is a question of too old IntelliJ or maybe the 'Jboss integration plugin' needs to be updated?

Comment: This link (http://blog.arungupta.me/wildfly9-netbeans-eclipse-intellij-openshift-maven/) indicates that IntelliJ 14 should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a a result of too old version of Intellij IDEA.
Or as you point out jboss integration plugin, which is bundled with IDEA itself.

There is also a trick to make IDEA belive it still supports newer version of WildFly.
We had it in place for some time in WildFly distro but was later removed as IDEA got official support for wildfly.

in short, this is the workaround https://github.com/wildfly/wildfly/blob/8.x/build/build.xml#L1551

all you need to do is to go to WILDFLY_HOME/modules/system/layers/base/org/jboss/as/version/main/ folder
and make copy of wildfly-version-xx.jar and rename the copy to jboss-as-version-xx.jar
where xx is the version of the wildfly.